# Focusing three.js camera

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, rotation

Im using the Three.js globe example from github and trying to make my own globe with some data. However I find it difficult to make the camera focus on given coordinate.

I use this function to convert the coords into points and then focus the camera but it doesn't do anything

```
 function searchCountry(lat,lng){

    var phi = (90 - lat) * Math.PI / 180;
    var theta = (180 - lng) * Math.PI / 180;

    camera.position.x = 200 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
    camera.position.y = 200 * Math.cos(phi);
    camera.position.z = 200 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
    camera.lookAt(mesh.position);
  }
```

The rest of the code is the same as the globe example. I pass the arguments from the index file like this:

```
<select class="country">
   <option data-lat="33" data-lng="65">Afghanistan</option>
</select>
```

+

```
jQuery(".country").change(function () {
    console.log(jQuery(".country :selected").data('lat'),jQuery(".country :selected").data('lng'));

    globe.searchCountry(jQuery(".country :selected").data('lat'),jQuery(".country :selected").data('lng'));
  });
```

I've echoed the values and it works correctly passing them and converting them its just that the globe stays the same it doesn't rotate to the given coords. Plus I'd like to add a certain amound of zoom in the rotate function so when it rotates i want it to be zoomed in, so if anyone knows it would be more then helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the format that is best suited for camera rotation in Three.js

```
camera.position.set( x_max*1.01, y_max*1.01, z_max*1.01 ).add(YourObject.position.clone());
```

So if you can change the last line of your Js codeso it fits the above syntax correctly, and it should work :

```
 function searchCountry(lat,lng){

    var phi = (90 - lat) * Math.PI / 180;
    var theta = (180 - lng) * Math.PI / 180;

    camera.position.x = 200 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
    camera.position.y = 200 * Math.cos(phi);
    camera.position.z = 200 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
    camera.lookAt(mesh.position); // <<-- Change this one to the format above!
  }
```

If you liked this anwser, please reward Accepted Anwser so other people dont think you still struggling with this. Thankyou

Comment: whats YourObject reffering to? also x_max, y_max and z_max all *1.01, I dont get it? Is YourObject the camera or the globe?

Comment: my function is now:
var phi = (90 - lat) * Math.PI / 180;
    var theta = (180 - lng) * Math.PI / 180;

    var x = 200 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
    var y = 200 * Math.cos(phi);
    var z = 200 * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);

    camera.position.set( x, y, z ).add(globe.position.clone());

Comment: it says globe undefined and if i put camera.position.clone() it doesnt give errors but it doesnt do anything

Comment: Ok @ViktorApostolski Does this link help? http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_dof.html

Comment: thanks for the effort but i cant seem to make it work. here is my whole globe.js file in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y7nvfgru/

Comment: the function is called searchCountry starting on line 220

Comment: could it be that the render function itself has this lines of code so it overwrites my function?
`rotation.x += (target.x - rotation.x) * 0.1;
    rotation.y += (target.y - rotation.y) * 0.1;
    

    distance += (distanceTarget - distance) * 0.3;

    camera.position.x = distance * Math.sin(rotation.x) * Math.cos(rotation.y);
    camera.position.y = distance * Math.sin(rotation.y);
    camera.position.z = distance * Math.cos(rotation.x) * Math.cos(rotation.y);

    camera.lookAt(mesh.position); `
@ewrwr